# Getting Lower-Order N Bits

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation

Is there any way you can get any integer's lower-order *n* bits (where *n* can be any number between 1 and 32) without previously pre-computing 32 bitmasks, one for each order, and using the `&` operator? I also don't want to be using `%` with powers of two, just bitwise operations.

*Edit:* Say, for example, that a user enters an integer `Num` and another integer `ShiftCount` with a value ranging from 1 to 32. I want to store in a third variable the bits that are lost in the operation `Num >> ShiftCount`.

Comment: You want to mask out the higher bits? Or get the lower bits as bools / ints?

Answer (score 10):

Something like `Num & ((1 << ShiftCount) - 1)`?

Answer (score 3):

How about this solution? It's strictly bit-twiddling—no math required:

```
public static int LowOrderBits( int value , int bits )
{
  if ( bits < 0 || bits > 32 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bits") ;
  return (int) ( ((uint)value) & ~(0xFFFFFFFF << bits) ) ;
}
```

@jdv-Jan de Van's solution requires subtraction, as does @Mark Sowul's (to obtain a value for `n`:

```
public static int LowOrderBits( int value , int bits )
{
  if ( bits < 0 || bits > 32 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bits") ;
  return (int) ( ((uint)value) & (0xFFFFFFFF >> (32-bits) ) ) ;
}
```

Subtraction is probably a more expensive operation than simple bit operations.

Answer (score 0):

How about starting with 1111...1111 (UInt32.MinValue), right-shifting it n bits (make sure to use uint so it doesn't sign-extend!), and then &-ing it with the value for which you want the lower-order bits?