# How to find remainder using bitwise operator?

Tags: bitwise-operators

Let's look at the following code.

```c
int x = 5>>1;
```

What it does is, it divides the given value by 2 power of 1 (which is 2) and it returns  the quotient. Is it possible to get remainder during bitwise operation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Lower-Order N Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354568/getting-lower-order-n-bits)

Answer (score 3):

A bitwise shift returns one value and thus "loses" any remainder.

For a power-of-two it can be paired with a bitmask that computes "what was lost" in the previously-applied shift.

```
int quotient = 5 >> 1;
int remainder = 5 & 0x01;
```

The mask value above can be computed with: `~((~(int)0) < 1)`; for a 32-bit int, `~0 == 0xFFFF`, `0xFFFF << 1 == 0xFFFE` and `~0xFFFE == 0x01`.

So, replacing with variables:

```
int n = ..;
int z = ..;
int quotient = n >> z;
int remainder = n & ~((~(int)0) << z);
```

Likewise, in the more general case, integer division (`/`) is paired with the modulo operator (`%`). Each operator only returns one value.

```
int n = ..;
int z = ..;
int p = 1 << z;
int quotient = n / p;
int remainder = n % p;
```

Answer (score 2):

a % b is equivalent to (b - 1) & a

Comment: This is true, but can you give a simple explanation for this

Comment: Keep in mind this is only true when b is a positive power of two.